# Non-interactive git restore for specific lines in a file

Tags: git, git-checkout

I have a modified and not staged file `myfile.txt`.

I want to `git restore` (or `git checkout`) `myfile.txt`, but it must undo the modifications done only within the line range 15-17. How to do that?

I've some solution by using interactive `-p` option, but I am not interested in this approach as I already know the line range I want to undo modifications.

Comment: Is this a one off ? or do you know you will have to repeatedly restore that file and keep a known range in it ?

Comment: @LeGEC I frequently know which line range I want to restore.

Comment: Possibly the *fastest* solution would be to just copy and paste the desired version of those 3 lines into your current file. So something like `git show <commit-id-or-maybe-HEAD>:myfile.txt | head -17 | tail -3`. Take that and paste it.

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in mode of `git restore` that would allow you to undo a change partially in a non-interactive way.